# Swift iOS -back button bug making scene show itself repeatedly before showing previous view

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, back-button, childviewcontroller

I have a navigation controller with 4 child views: vc1, vc2, vc3, and vc4. I have them all connected to one another using storyboards and not programmatically. I have a button in each scene that has the segue connected to it that pushes on the following scene and I get the built in back button with it.

This weird bug that happened to me today has only happened to me once before and that was about 2-3 months ago. I tried to reproduce it but since it's so random I can't.

Anyhow when I pressed the back button in vc3 to get back to vc2, vc3 kept showing itself (vc3) several times. It was as if it was going back to itself. After about 3-4 times of it showing itself it eventually went back to vc2.

I don't have any code to show only because this is in IB. When it first happened I found a blog post on it that said it was a common back button problem but the post didn't say anything about a fix. I dismissed as a 1 time error but today it happened again on the same exact scene which means it can happen again.

1 thing to note is I had an iPhone 5 and I saw it happen a once or twice inside the Settings menu. It never happened again.

Anyone know anything about this issue?

Comment: Try to make the buttons custom from IB itself, not sure but may be this could help

Comment: @Ishika Thanks for the help. What do you mean by try to make them from IB itself? That's where they are made

Comment: Instead of default button change it to custom from identity inspector

Comment: @Ishika I was thinking about just overriding it in viewDidLoad by adding a programmatic button. It's still a very strange issue. I would like to know what causes the problem. But in the mean time I'm going to use your suggestion just programmatically.

Comment: Yope sometimes storyboard brings up some wierd issues...but if you do so programtically, such issues wont show up ever

Comment: @Ishika Thanks :)